# Find opened process in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, tasklist

I'm trying to write code which loops and tells if a certain process is opened or not. It should be a loop that will show me in real time if the process is opened or not. In other words, a text will change when the program is opened and change again when it's closed. Instead what I got was a flood with the same text and it doesn't show the 'echos' below it.

I tried this:

```
@echo off 
goto xera
:start 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" | find /I "notepad.exe" > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 ECHO is opened
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 ECHO isnt opened 
:xera
    set /p "=Status: " <nul &call :start //the code got 'stuck' here
    ECHO Text 2 (doesnt show)
    pause>nul
```

Comment: It's not going to ever show "Text 2" because you call a subroutine before you ever get to it. You will literally never reach that code. But on the bright side, your process status checker works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not terminating your sub-routine `:start` correctly. Try the following:

```
@echo off 
goto xera
:start 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" | find /I "notepad.exe" > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 ECHO is opened
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 ECHO isnt opened
exit /b
:xera
set /p "=Status: " <nul &call :start
ECHO Text 2 (doesnt show)
pause>nul
```

I inserted `exit /b` which tells the command interpreter to return to the command after the `call` statement that actually called it. You could also use `goto :EOF` instead. Type `call /?` for more information on how to call sub-routines in batch.

Comment: yeah, but, if I use 'goto :eof' the code will run just once, but what I want is the code to keep in loop to be always saying if 'process.exe' is opened.

Comment: What portion of code should be in a loop? When you append ` & goto :xera` after the `call :start` command, does the code then do what you want??

Comment: That part called `:start`. In Delphi would be something like this: `procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
if ProcessVerify('notepad.exe') then //ProcessVerify is the function to verify a opened process
Label1.caption:='is opened';
else
Label1.caption:='isn't opened';`

Comment: If I get it right, you could simply replace `call :start` by `goto :start` in your original code... But what I still don't get: should `Text 2` be echoed at some point, and if so, when?

Comment: Nevermind. I rebuild the code. I would have to rebuild it anyway, however, I don't think that 'timer' would work. Thanks bro.

Comment: You're welcome! If you need to establish a delay in an endless loop in batch, you could use: `timeout /T 2 /NOBREAK > nul` (this tells to wait for 2 seconds before continuing with the next line of code; `/NOBREAK` disables premature termination of the command by key-presses; `> nul` supresses display messages).