# Checking if program is open. If not, open it

Tags: batch-file, task, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am running multiple exe files that open the CMD for a console. It is the same program multiple time, but different instances, so in different folders. The sometimes crash randomly and I am trying to make a batch file that reopens them when they close. I only want 1 instance of each program running at once.

Comment: This seems more in-line for [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) in my opinion... but without any details, or an attempt at coding, isn't really a great fit for SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find opened process in Windows batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021087/find-opened-process-in-windows-batch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:loop
c:\windows\notepad.exe
Goto Loop
```

In a batch file the script waits for a program to exit. So this starts notepad whenever it closes.

Comment: The programs I am opening are batch files and I just noticed that when opening a different batch file it opens inside the current one, thus closing the loop.

Comment: You have to use `call` when using batch files. `call c:\batch.bat`. For compatibility reasons batch files transfer control to each other. Call makes it a returnable transfer. See `call /?`. See my answer yesterday on the three different ways of starting programs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558164/how-to-use-a-bat-file-to-run-other-bats-and-have-each-one-in-a-seperate-cmd/38558229#38558229

Comment: I tried doing that. Sorry for being so confusing, I am opening an exe that opens a console, which is why I said batch file but that was the wrong thing to say I apologise. I tried using call but the console still opens in the same cmd if that makes sense. I tried start "" "path" but then it just opens the file infinitely. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Edit your question with all details including all filenames.

Comment: `Stert /b etc` starts a console process in a new window. See `start /?`. Note if using quotes the first set of quotes must be window's title.